# Can someone please help me understand the case function?

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL data base. I have to make two columns. The first column is the length of the employee name(I have that) The second column is title of courtesy and then the last name of employee.

My problem is how do i add the case function to have Ms displayed as miss, mr. as mister and dr as doctor. I do not understand. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code i have so far:

```
SELECT 'Your full name is ' + CAST(LEN(FirstName) + LEN(LastName) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' character(s).' AS [Length of Employee Name]
       , TitleOfCourtesy + LastName AS Title
  FROM dbo.Employees
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all I fixed it I had to add the period after like mr.

```
SELECT        'Your full name is ' + CAST(LEN(FirstName) + LEN(LastName) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' character(s).' AS [Length of Employee Name]
    ,   CASE TitleOfCourtesy 
            WHEN 'Mr.' THEN 'Mister ' 
            WHEN 'mrs. ' THEN 'Miss' 
            WHEN 'Ms.' THEN 'Miss ' 
            WHEN 'Dr.' THEN 'Doctor ' 
            ELSE '' END 
            + TitleOfCourtesy + LastName
            AS title
FROM            dbo.Employees
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
select
  ... your previous things here ...
  case TitleOfCourtesy 
    when 'Mr' then 'Mister '
    when 'Ms' then 'Miss '
    when 'Dr' then 'Doctor '
    else '' end + LastName as Title
```

Comment: when i try this im only returning the last name and not title

Comment: Then your codes in TitleOfCourtesy might not match the ones in the case statement. Since you didn't provide the exact data that was my guess how those are written.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT  'Your full name is ' + CAST(LEN(FirstName) + LEN(LastName) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' character(s).' AS [Length of Employee Name], 
CASE 
    WHEN TitleOfCourtesy = 'Ms' THEN 'Miss '
    WHEN TitleOfCourtesy = 'Mr' THEN 'Mister '
    WHEN TitleOfCourtesy = 'dr' THEN 'Doctor ' END + LastName AS Title
FROM  dbo.Employees
```

Comment: When i try this im returning null for title

Comment: Then either TitleOfCourtesy is null or it's not one of the options in the case. it may contain trailing spaces or something like that